# How to set a background image and position with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code which allows me to have a colour fade in and out when hovering over a link, but I want an background image to fade with it. I'm not sure how to set the background image and position within my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $imageUrl = "../images/TopNavigationArrows.png";
   var cssBg = ?

   $(".link").hover(function() {
       // Hover State
       $(this).animate({ color: "#FFEFCA" }, 200);

   },function() {
       // Default State
       $(this).animate({ color: "#FFF" }, 200);
   });
});
```

Comment: Can't animate in and out a background image. Your option would use regular image's with display:none;, position:absolutel;, width/height:100%; and position:fixed;(or absolute with a scrollTop function to keep position sane for some browsers)

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate a background image to fade in.  What you might have to do is add an additional element containing the background image at a lower z-index from your current elements and fade that in with the normal `fadeIn/fadeOut` functions.

Comment: @ohg - hey! that looks pretty good!  I know a few people who would pay for that kind of animations ;)  Hehe... Seriously though, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the position of the image in html like this:

<
button onclick="location.href='01.html'" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 200px ;"> 
<
img src="left.gif"

> <
>   /button>

Answer (score -1):

You can set css properties for any element as follows:

```
$(this).css({
    background-image:url('image.gif'),
    background-repeat:no-repeat,
    background-attachment:fixed,
    background-position:center, 
    top: 100,
    left: 100
});
```

I think that's what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, that's how you set CSS properties - but its not what the OP asked.  They want to **fade in** a `background-image` property.

Comment: Ummm, @Lix, I am not sure whether you are doing it or not (if not, ignore this), but continually downvoting answers just because the answer-er did not comprehend the question correctly is outright meaningless and high-handed, not to mention stupid.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to animate colors, you have to use jQuery color animation UI, jQuery doesn't have the functionality by itself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "continually downvoting answers".  But if I see an answer that simply doesn't answer the question at all I'll vote it down.  It doesn't really matter too much if it's from misreading the question or something that I don't feel is helpful.  It's not an attack on the user at all, I'm voting on the content.

Comment: Your answer here, for example simply simply doesn't help the OP that much.  I'm not saying its wrong - I'm just saying that in this context it is not helpful.  This is only my one opinion.  If an answer was given and at some stage the poster realizes that it in fact doesn't answer the question, that post should be removed as it is irrelevant.

Comment: When you remove a post you get the reputation back (if its downvotes) or taken away if its upvotes).  I've removed my downvote because I feel that that is what is bothering you.  But I still feel that it should be removed.

Comment: Ok then. I will remember that and think thrice before posting an answer. I am a member of many other coding forums, many of them with gamification as here, but nowhere have I seen users so paranoid about voting, as if every answer, every comment has to be voted. But yes, perhaps that is instrumental in maintaining a high standard of answers. Thanks.

Comment: [so] is not like the other forums :P  It's not a forum at all.